# Migrating from DB2, SQL Server to YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

This is regarding migration from a different source DB to YugabyteDB.
I can see that 'YugabyteDB Voyager' supports Postgres, Aurora, MySQL and Oracle only as source database for Migration to YugabyteDB.
How to migrate SQL Server and DB2 database to Yugabyte?
Appreciate if someone can throw more insight into this topic as I have a use case where we are evaluating YB as the target database and we have SQL Server and DB2 as source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both SQLServer and DB2 as a source are on the roadmap for YugabyteDB Voyager, but not been scheduled or prioritized for any release yet.

You can use [pgloader](https://blog.yugabyte.com/migrating-mysql-to-yugabytedb-using-pgloader/) for offline migration. For live migration you can try [blitzz.io](http://blitzz.io)